# Efficiently building a large (200 MM line) dataframe

Tags: r

I am attempting to build a large  (~200 MM line) dataframe in R. Each entry in the dataframe will consist of approximately 10 digits (e.g. 1234.12345). The code is designed to walk through a list, subtract an item in position [i] from every item after [i], but not the items before [i] (If I was putting the output into a matrix it would be a triangular matrix). The code is simple and works fine on smaller lists, but I am wondering if there is a faster or more efficient way to do this? I assume the first part of the answer is going to entail "don't use a nested for loop," but I am not sure what the alternatives are.

The idea is that this will be an "edge list" for a social network analysis graph. Once I have 'outlist' I will reduce the number of edges based on some criteria(<,>,==,) so the final list (and graph) won't be quite so ponderous.

```
#Fake data of same approximate dimensions as real data
dlist<-sample(1:20,20, replace=FALSE) 
#purge the output list before running the loop
rm(outlist)
outlist<-data.frame()

for(i in 1:(length(dlist)-1)){
         for(j in (i+1):length(dlist)){

             outlist<-rbind(outlist, c(dlist[i],dlist[j], dlist[j]-dlist[i]))

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC your final dataset will be ~200 million rows by 3 columns, all of type `numeric`, which takes a total space of:

```
200e6 (rows) * 3 (cols) * 8 (bytes) / (1024 ^ 3)
# ~ 4.5GB
```

That's quite a big data, where it's essential to avoid copies wherever possible.

Here's a method that uses `data.table` package's unexported (internal) `vecseq` function (written in `C` and is fast + memory efficient) and makes use of it's assignment by reference operator `:=`, to avoid copies.

```
fn1 <- function(x) {
    require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
    lx = length(x)
    vx = as.integer(lx * (lx-1)/2)
    # R v3.1.0 doesn't copy on doing list(.) - so should be even more faster there
    ans = setDT(list(v1 = rep.int(head(x,-1L), (lx-1L):1L), 
                v2=x[data.table:::vecseq(2:lx, (lx-1L):1, vx)]))
    ans[, v3 := v2-v1]
}
```

#### Benchmarking:

I'll benchmark with functions from other answers on your data dimensions. Note that my benchmark is on R v3.0.2, but `fn1()` should give better performance (both speed and memory) on R v3.1.0 because `list(.)` doesn't result in copy anymore.

```
fn2 <- function(x) {
    diffmat <- outer(x, x, "-")
    ss <- which(upper.tri(diffmat), arr.ind = TRUE)
    data.frame(v1 = x[ss[,1]], v2 = x[ss[,2]], v3 = diffmat[ss])
}

fn3 <- function(x) {
    idx <- combn(seq_along(x), 2)
    out2 <- data.frame(v1=x[idx[1, ]], v2=x[idx[2, ]])
    out2$v3 <- out2$v2-out2$v1
    out2
}

set.seed(45L)
x = runif(20e3L)
system.time(ans1 <- fn1(x))  ## 18  seconds + ~8GB  (peak) memory usage
system.time(ans2 <- fn2(x))  ## 158 seconds + ~19GB (peak) memory usage
system.time(ans3 <- fn3(x))  ## 809 seconds + ~12GB (peak) memory usage
```

Note that `fn2()` due to use of `outer` requires quite a lot of memory (peak memory usage was >=19GB) and is slower than `fn1()`. `fn3()` is just very very slow (due to `combn`, and unnecessary copy).

Comment: Yes, my attempt with fn3 crashed at ~10mins with:  
"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.8 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In as.vector(x[, i]) :  Reached total allocation of 8174Mb: see help(memory.size)"

I am trying this solution next.

Comment: Ok, this is the fastest solution but R is not letting me allocate that vector for some reason. I am running R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10), on Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit). Memory.limit() says I have 8174 mb available. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try removing `ans[, v3 := v2-v1]` step and run again? It'd require ~1.6GB lesser.. Then maybe write it to a file and use awk/sed/perl over command line to create the 3rd col..

Answer (score 2):

Another way to create that data is

```
#Sample Data
N <- 20
set.seed(15) #for reproducibility
dlist <- sample(1:N,N, replace=FALSE)
```

we could do

```
idx <- combn(1:N,2)
out2 <- data.frame(i=dlist[idx[1, ]], j=dlist[idx[2, ]])
out2$dist <- out2$j-out2$i
```

This uses `combn` to create all paris of indices in the data.set rather than doing loops. This allows us to build the data.frame all at once rather than adding a row at a time.

We compare that to

```
out1 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(length(dlist)-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):length(dlist)){
        out1<-rbind(out1, c(dlist[i],dlist[j], dlist[j]-dlist[i]))
    }
}
```

we see that

```
all(out1==out2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Plus, if we compare with microbenchmark we see that

```
microbenchmark(loops(), combdata())
# Unit: microseconds
#        expr       min        lq     median         uq       max neval
#     loops() 30888.403 32230.107 33764.7170 34821.2850 82891.166   100
#  combdata()   684.316   800.384   873.5015   940.9215  4285.627   100
```

The method that doesn't use loops is much faster.

Comment: Thank you! That seems like what I want, now to see if it works on the real data...

Comment: I'm not the down-voter. But, have you seen the `combn()` function? It does use a `while()` loop, written in R.

Answer (score 1):

You can always start with a triangular matrix and then make your dataframe directly from that:

```
vec <- 1:10

diffmat <- outer(vec,vec,"-")
ss <- which(upper.tri(diffmat),arr.ind = TRUE)

data.frame(one = vec[ss[,1]], 
           two = vec[ss[,2]], 
           diff = diffmat[ss])
```

Comment: Where do you use the values of dlist here?

Comment: @MrFlick `vec <- dlist`. The results are the same, but sorted differently and the 3rd column has the opposite sign.

Comment: Right, @GSee.  I wanted something with a triangular matrix, since the OP mentioned one.  But just as I finished my answer I realized that I should have used `combn` instead -- and there was @MrFlick with that approach! well done :)

Comment: I had played with a triangular matrix earlier but the size of that object (with the real data) has prevented R from actually creating it on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to preallocate out list,  this will significantly increase the speed of your code.  By preallocating I mean creating an output structure that already has the desired size,  but filled with for example NA's.